# What's the smallest starting library you can have in commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

My understanding is, your commander deck is 100 cards.  And you take commander/companions etc. out of your deck before you start and put them in the command zone.

The smallest library I can come up with, is 97 cards.  Where you start with a pair of commander partners, and a companion.

Is there a way to make your library even smaller?

Addendum: I asked the question thinking of the "size of initial library" version of the question.  i.e. identifying if there are any rules loop holes for deck construction that could reduce the deck size.  That said, Allure's answer is *awesome*, and makes it clear that there are ways "in game" to get to a smaller library that could be important for some decks, I hadn't thought of that avenue, and find that to be a fine answer as well.  Even if that wasn't my initial question.

Comment: The companion isn't in your deck, it's in your sideboard. That example starts with 98 cards.

Comment: A companion is card number 101, it does not count towards the 100 cards in a commander deck and thus won't reduce the cards in the library.

Comment: Re "there are ways "in game" to get to a smaller library that could be important for some decks", it's actually common for Vintage Dredge decks (which are entirely reliant on finding Bazaar of Baghdad in their starting hand) to run 4x Serum Powder. See example list https://www.mtgtop8.com/event?e=52325&d=588461&f=VI. These decks are happy to mulligan all the way down to 1 card, to find Bazaar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the answer is 98:

- A companion does *not* count as part of the 100 cards; refer to comprehensive rule 702.139a: "Before the game begins, you may reveal one card you own **from outside the game** with a companion ability whose condition is fulfilled by your starting deck" (my emphasis).
- You can never have more than two Commanders; refer to comprehensive rule 702.124g: "no partner ability or combination of partner abilities can ever let a player have more than two commanders." "Partner abilities" here is defined by 702.124a and includes all of the "base" partner, partner with [name], friends forever, backgrounds and Doctor's companion.
- While it's difficult to prove a negative, I'm going to assert there's nothing else which can allow you to reduce the size of your starting library.

(Rules references from the [2024-02-06 Comprehensive Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2024/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020240206.pdf))

Comment: Technically speaking, there is another mechanic that allows you to reduce the size of your starting library: If you for some reason do allow ante cards in your group (which would be a deviation from the rules, since they are normally banned for Commander and all other formats), but don't play for ante, you get to remove those cards from the deck before playing. There are nine such cards, which means that the actual smallest starting deck size would be 89 under these very specific and constructed conditions.

Comment: @TheThirdMan If you're looking at cards which aren't legal in Commander, also [Advantageous Proclamation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382206), and probably some un-set cards as well. But at some point you have to start restricting things to things legal in the format as defined by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can play [Serum Powder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Serum%20Powder) and exile 7 cards if you draw it in your opening hand, therefore "starting" with 91 cards.

You can play [Shahrazad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shahrazad) with 0 cards left in your library, to start with 0 cards. (But this card is banned in Commander ...)

[Karn Liberated](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karn%20Liberated) can also restart a game with a smaller library. It's easy to imagine a situation where Karn exiles everything and you start with 0 cards.

Comment: The Serum Powder example doesn't make sense to me. You only use Serum Powder like that after you have drawn an opening hand, and if you're counting from that point, the starting library size is always 7 fewer cards, because your opening hand isn't in your library at that point.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I suppose it comes down to how you define it and/or what the OP is looking for. With Serum Powder, you have exiled some cards before anything happens in the game, so one could reasonably argue that you are starting the game with a smaller deck (in fact last I saw that's why people play Serum Powder). It could conceivably be what the OP needs.

Comment: I know what Serum Powder does. I guess my point is more that if you say that Serum Powder is reducing your starting library size, then that means that you are counting the starting library size after drawing your opening hand. That means that the default commander starting library size is 92 (-1 for commander, -7 for opening hand), and the size with Serum Powder is 85 (-7 for exiled hand). But that's clearly not how the question defined it because it (incorrectly) states that the minimum they could come up with was 97.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's very much semantics. One can argue that your starting deck size is the number of cards in your library when you start to draw your opening hand, and the cards exiled by Serum Powder do not count as your opening hand.

Comment: If you look through the "starting the game" procedure in rules section 103, you start with a deck, and then in rule 103.3 you shuffle that deck and it becomes your library. I don't see any reasonable way to define "starting library" other than "your library, at the very start of its lifetime as your library".

Comment: Again, I view this as *completely semantics*, and any further argument is pointless since it's fully dependent on what the OP needs the answer for.

Comment: In an effort to describe *why* it would be relevant: There are two reasons I can think of why a player was to reduce their deck size: To increase the chance of drawing a certain card, and to reduce the library to zero cards as easily as possible. Serum Powder appears to be helpful with both, and while I completely agree with @murgatroid99 here, I still consider this a helpful answer for the stated reason - although I will say I would prefer a rephrasing to that end as well.

Comment: Is the 90 cards value correct, since apparently companions aren't part of the 100?